# JavaFx: How to apply validation on two GridPanes nodes simultaneously?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm creating an application using Javafx in which in which I'm creating two different GridPanes say GridPane A and GridPane B. In GridPane A I've TextFields and GridPane B I've TextFields, Checkboxes and DatePickers, all the nodes I'm creating at run time. Under both of the GridPanes A and B I've a button like this:

[image]

What I want is to disable the button until both the entries of both GridPane A and GridPane B. I'm able on achieve it but only on GridPane A like this

First by checking if all the TextFields of GridPane A are filled and not empty:

```
private static boolean isAllFilled(GridPane tableA){
     for(Node node : tableA.getChildren()){ // cycle through every component in the table (GridPane)
         if(node instanceof TextField){ // if it's a TextField
         // after removing the leading spaces, check if it's empty
             if(((TextField)node).getText().trim().isEmpty()){
                     return false; // if so, return false
             }
         }       
     }
     return true;
  }
```

Then validating the TableA (GridPane A) and adding listener:

```
private void validateTable(GridPane tableA, Button button) {

     for(Node node : tableA.getChildren()){ // cycle through every component in the table (GridPane)
        if(node instanceof TextField){ // if it's a TextField
          ((TextField)node).textProperty().addListener((obs, old, newV)->{ // add a change listener to every TextField
          // then check if the new value is not empty AND all other TextFields are not empty
            if(!newV.trim().isEmpty()&&isAllFilled(tableA)){ 
               button.setDisable(false); // then make the button active again
            }
            else{
                button.setDisable(true); // or else, make it disable until it achieves the required condition 
            }
        });
     }    
  }

  }
```

I want to apply validation simultaneously on both GridPane A and GridPane B, like right now my program is validating GridPane A entries and disabling/enabling the button but I want is to keep button disabled unless both GridPane A and GridPane B entries are filled.

Comment: From a usability perspective, you may want to consider leaving the button enabled at all times, and if the user presses it when any of the text fields are empty, show an [error Alert](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.AlertType.html#ERROR) with an informative message.  It might not be obvious to the user why the button is disabled or how to cause it to be enabled.

Comment: You're right but it's requirement of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you're checking if all `TextFields` are *Filled* in Table A, You can do the same for the second Table (Table B):

```
// cycle through every component in tableA
private static boolean isAllFilled(GridPane tableA, GridPane tableB){
    for(Node node : tableA.getChildren()){
        if(node instanceof TextField){
            if(((TextField)node).getText().trim().isEmpty()){
                    return false;
            }
        }       
    }

     // cycle through every component in tableB
    for(Node node : tableB.getChildren()){ 
        if(node instanceof TextField){
            if(((TextField)node).getText().trim().isEmpty()){
                    return false;
            }
        }       
    }

    return true; // if all are filled / not empty
}
```

Now with every change in any `TextField` either in *TableA* or *TableB*, it will check if all `TextFields` in both tables are *Filled*.

---

**Then Add tableB to the `validateTable` method, like this:**

```
private void validateTable(GridPane tableA, GridPane tableB, Button button){

    // add a change listener to every TextField in tableA
     for(Node node : tableA.getChildren()){ 
        if(node instanceof TextField){
          ((TextField)node).textProperty().addListener((obs, old, newV)->{ 
            if(!newV.trim().isEmpty()&&isAllFilled(tableA, tableB)){ 
               button.setDisable(false);
            }
            else{
                button.setDisable(true);
            }
         });
      }    
   }

   // add a change listener to every TextField in tableB
     for(Node node : tableB.getChildren()){ 
        if(node instanceof TextField){
          ((TextField)node).textProperty().addListener((obs, old, newV)->{ 
            if(!newV.trim().isEmpty()&&isAllFilled(tableA, tableB)){ 
               button.setDisable(false);
            }
            else{
                button.setDisable(true);
            }
         });
       }    
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked merci @Yahya :) Another thing if I want to validate CheckBox and DatePicker, I've to do like this `if(node instanceof TextField && node instanceof CheckBox && node instanceof DatePicker)` ?

Comment: @Junaid I'm glad I could help :). Regarding you question, it should be `if(node instanceof TextField){// add change listener}` and after it add `else if(node instanceof CheckBox){// add change listener}` and so on..

Comment: Okay, and @Yahya can I compare two column textfields values with each other for example if column 1 TextField value is lesser than column 3 TextField value keep the button disabled. and show border of that specif column 3 textfield which has greater value in red color. two comparing textfields should be on the same row but they can be in different columns.

Comment: @Junaid To be honest I did not understand what you mean fully. Would you please provide a `gif` image or any other draw of what you want to achieve (Please remember that I don't have all your code so I may not be fully aware of the complete image / nor updated with all changes you did in your project).

Comment: Ok @Yahya I'll post it in another question.

Comment: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312354/javafx-how-to-compare-values-of-dynamically-created-textfields-inside-gridpane) @Yahya I've posted a question.