# JavaFx: How to update text of dynimically created TextFields inside GridPane?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm developing an app in JavaFx, in which which I'm dynamically creating TextFeids and CheckBoxes inside GridPane like this:

[image]

I'm adding numbers which user will enter in TextField 1 and TextField 2 and displaying in TextField 3 like this using listener:

[image]

**Problem:** What I want is when user will check the CheckBox it should add 10 to the value already present in the TextField 3 of **(same row as of triggered CheckBox)** and update the text of TextField 3, and when user will uncheck the CheckBox it should subtract 10 from the value present in the TextField 3 of **(same row as of triggered CheckBox)** and update the text of TextField 3. I tried to do it but it's not working (not adding and removing):

[image]

This is how I'm creating GridPane:

```
 public static GridPane table(int rows){
        GridPane table = new GridPane();

        for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
            TextField textField = new TextField();
            textField.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            TextField textField2 = new TextField();
            textField2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("Check Box");
            checkBox.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
            checkBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            TextField textField3 = new TextField();
            textField3.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            table.add(textField, 0, i);
            table.add(textField2, 1, i);
            table.add(checkBox , 2, i);
            table.add(textField3,3, i);

            GridPane.setMargin(textField, new Insets(5));
            GridPane.setMargin(textField2, new Insets(5));
            GridPane.setMargin(checkBox, new Insets(5));
            GridPane.setMargin(textField3, new Insets(5));
         }
        table.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        return table;
    }
```

A method to return a component from Table at specific row and column

```
public static Node getComponent (int row, int column, GridPane table) {
     for (Node component : table.getChildren()) { 
         if(GridPane.getRowIndex(component) == row && 
                         GridPane.getColumnIndex(component) == column) {
             return component;
         }
     }

     return null;
 }
```

This is how I'm adding:

```
    public void add(GridPane table, int numRows){

       for(int i=0; i<numRows; i++){
           try {

                int valueA = Integer.parseInt(((TextField)(getComponent (i, 0, table))).getText());
                System.out.println(valueA);
                int valueB = Integer.parseInt(((TextField)(getComponent (i, 1, table))).getText());
                System.out.println(valueB);

                int add = valueA+valueB;

                String addToString = Integer.toString(add);

                ((TextField)(getComponent (i, 3, table))).setText(addToString);

                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                  System.out.print("Caught the NullPointerException");
                    }
       }

    }
```

**Problem:** Addition and subtraction using CheckBox:

```
     public void addPause(GridPane table, int numRows){

                for(int i=0; i<numRows; i++){

                boolean pause = ((CheckBox)(getComponent (i, 2, table))).isSelected();
                int getTextValue = Integer.parseInt(((TextField)(getComponent (i, 3, table))).getText());

                int addPause = getTextValue+10;
                int removePause = addPause-10;

                String addPToString = Integer.toString(addPause);
                String removePToString = Integer.toString(removePause);

                if (pause) {
                    ((TextField)(getComponent (i, 3, table))).setText(addPToString);
                } else {
                    ((TextField)(getComponent (i, 3, table))).setText(removePToString);
                }
       }
    }
```

This is how I'm triggering using listeners:

```
        for(Node node : table.getChildren()){ 
          if(node instanceof TextField){
             ((TextField)node).textProperty().addListener((obs, old, newV)->{
               add(table, numRows);
           });
         }
          else if(node instanceof CheckBox){
              ((CheckBox)node).selectedProperty().addListener((obs, old, newV)->{ 
                addPause(table, numRows);
             });
           }
       }
```

Comment: Why don't you just add the listener to the check box when you create it? I gave you a perfectly workable solution to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312354/javafx-how-to-compare-values-of-dynamically-created-textfields-inside-gridpane): the exact same approach will work just as well here.

Comment: @Jamed_D your example was good but I need to refactor the whole bunch of code.

Comment: Why do you need to refactor it, and what has that got to do with this question (or your previous one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312354/javafx-how-to-compare-values-of-dynamically-created-textfields-inside-gridpane), just register the listeners for the controls at the point you create them.

You can actually just use a single listener (in each row) for the two text fields and check box, and update the third text box when any of those change. For example:

```
public static GridPane table(int rows){
    GridPane table = new GridPane();

    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        TextField textField2 = new TextField();
        textField2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("Check Box");
        checkBox.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
        checkBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        TextField textField3 = new TextField();
        textField3.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        table.add(textField, 0, i);
        table.add(textField2, 1, i);
        table.add(checkBox , 2, i);
        table.add(textField3,3, i);

        ChangeListener<Object> listener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
            updateTotalField(textField.getText(), textField2.getText(), checkBox.isSelected(), textField3);

        textField.textProperty().addListener(listener);
        textField2.textProperty().addListener(listener);
        checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(listener);

        GridPane.setMargin(textField, new Insets(5));
        GridPane.setMargin(textField2, new Insets(5));
        GridPane.setMargin(checkBox, new Insets(5));
        GridPane.setMargin(textField3, new Insets(5));
     }
    table.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    return table;
}

private static void updateTotalField(String text1, String text2, boolean addPause, TextField output) {
    int value1 = parseText(text1);
    int value2 = parseText(text2);
    int total = value1 + value2 ;
    if (addPause) {
        total += 10 ;
    }
    output.setText(Integer.toString(total));
}

private static int parseText(String text) {
    // if text is a valid integer:
    if (text.matches("\\d+")) {
        return Integer.parseInt(text);
    } else {
        return 0 ;
    }
}
```

Now you can get rid of the `add` and `addPause` method, and the chunk of code you posted where you iterate through the child nodes of the grid pane and add listeners. You may be able to get rid of the `getComponent()` method to, unless you need it elsewhere.

Here is the code as a SSCCE

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableOfControlsInGridPane extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(table(10));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public GridPane table(int rows){
        GridPane table = new GridPane();

        for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
            TextField textField = new TextField();
            textField.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            TextField textField2 = new TextField();
            textField2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("Check Box");
            checkBox.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
            checkBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            TextField textField3 = new TextField();
            textField3.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            table.add(textField, 0, i);
            table.add(textField2, 1, i);
            table.add(checkBox , 2, i);
            table.add(textField3,3, i);

            ChangeListener<Object> listener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
                updateTotalField(textField.getText(), textField2.getText(), checkBox.isSelected(), textField3);

            textField.textProperty().addListener(listener);
            textField2.textProperty().addListener(listener);
            checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(listener);

            GridPane.setMargin(textField, new Insets(5));
            GridPane.setMargin(textField2, new Insets(5));
            GridPane.setMargin(checkBox, new Insets(5));
            GridPane.setMargin(textField3, new Insets(5));
         }
        table.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        return table;
    }

    private void updateTotalField(String text1, String text2, boolean addPause, TextField output) {
        int value1 = parseText(text1);
        int value2 = parseText(text2);
        int total = value1 + value2 ;
        if (addPause) {
            total += 10 ;
        }
        output.setText(Integer.toString(total));
    }

    private int parseText(String text) {
        // if text is a valid integer:
        if (text.matches("\\d+")) {
            return Integer.parseInt(text);
        } else {
            return 0 ;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and a screenshot:
[image]

Since Java is an object-oriented language, it would probably seem more appropriate to do this in an object-oriented way in the first place. I have no idea what data you are representing in this view, but you should define a class that encapsulates the data in a single row:

```
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;

// Obviously use a more sensible name for the class:
public class RowData {

    private final IntegerProperty firstValue = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private final IntegerProperty secondValue = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private final BooleanProperty includePause = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private final ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper total = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper();

    public RowData() {
        total.bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> {
            int total = getFirstValue() + getSecondValue() ;
            if (isIncludePause()) {
                total += 10 ;
            }
            return total ;
        }, firstValue, secondValue, includePause));
    }

    public final IntegerProperty firstValueProperty() {
        return this.firstValue;
    }


    public final int getFirstValue() {
        return this.firstValueProperty().get();
    }


    public final void setFirstValue(final int firstValue) {
        this.firstValueProperty().set(firstValue);
    }


    public final IntegerProperty secondValueProperty() {
        return this.secondValue;
    }


    public final int getSecondValue() {
        return this.secondValueProperty().get();
    }


    public final void setSecondValue(final int secondValue) {
        this.secondValueProperty().set(secondValue);
    }


    public final BooleanProperty includePauseProperty() {
        return this.includePause;
    }


    public final boolean isIncludePause() {
        return this.includePauseProperty().get();
    }


    public final void setIncludePause(final boolean includePause) {
        this.includePauseProperty().set(includePause);
    }


    public final ReadOnlyIntegerProperty totalProperty() {
        return this.total.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }


    public final int getTotal() {
        return this.totalProperty().get();
    }

}
```

Then a class to display those data:

```
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class RowDataView {

    private final TextField firstValueField ;
    private final TextField secondValueField ;
    private final CheckBox includePauseBox ;
    private final TextField totalField ;

    public RowDataView(RowData data) {

        firstValueField = new TextField();
        bindToStringProperty(data.firstValueProperty(), firstValueField.textProperty());

        secondValueField = new TextField();
        bindToStringProperty(data.secondValueProperty(), secondValueField.textProperty());

        includePauseBox = new CheckBox();
        data.includePauseProperty().bind(includePauseBox.selectedProperty());

        totalField = new TextField();
        totalField.setEditable(false);
        totalField.textProperty().bind(data.totalProperty().asString());
    }

    public void addToGridPane(GridPane pane, int row, int firstValueColumn, int secondValueColumn, int checkboxColumn, int totalColumn) {
        pane.add(firstValueField, firstValueColumn, row);
        pane.add(secondValueField, secondValueColumn, row);
        pane.add(includePauseBox, checkboxColumn, row);
        pane.add(totalField, totalColumn, row);
    }

    public void addToGridPane(GridPane pane, int row, int column) {
        addToGridPane(pane, row, column, column+1, column+2, column+3);
    }

    public void addToGridPane(GridPane pane, int row) {
        addToGridPane(pane, row, 0);
    }

    private void bindToStringProperty(IntegerProperty p, StringProperty s) {
        p.bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(
                () -> {
                    if (s.get().matches("\\d+")) {
                        return Integer.parseInt(s.get());
                    }
                    return 0 ;
                }, s));
    }
}
```

and here is some test code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableOfControlsInGridPane extends Application {

    private final List<RowData> data = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(table(10), 800, 800);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public GridPane table(int rows){
        GridPane table = new GridPane();
        table.getStyleClass().add("data-grid");

        data.clear();

        for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){

            RowData rowData = new RowData();
            data.add(rowData);

            RowDataView rowDataView = new RowDataView(rowData);
            rowDataView.addToGridPane(table, i);
         }
        table.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        return table;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I moved the styles to the style sheet (`style.css`):

```css
.data-grid {
    -fx-background-color: purple ;
    -fx-hgap: 10 ;
    -fx-vgap: 10 ;  
}
.data-grid .text-field, .data-grid .check-box {
    -fx-alignment: center ;
}
.data-grid .check-box {
    -fx-text-fill: white ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @James_D for your detailed answer, I'll try to implement it in the OOP way.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve that is by adding a **`ChangeListener`** to every **`CheckBox`** in the **`Table(GridPane)`**, something like this:

```
/**
* This method to change the current value of the TextField at
* column 3 in the Table(GridPane) by ten 
* @param table
*/
private static void changeByTen(GridPane table){
   // loop through every node in the GridPane
   for(Node node : table.getChildren()){
       // and for every CheckBox
       if(node instanceof CheckBox){
          // add change listener to the Selected Property 
          ((CheckBox)node).selectedProperty().addListener((obs, unSelected, selected)->{
              // get the TextField at third column that corresponds to this CehckBox
              TextField targetTextFeild = 
                      ((TextField)getComponent(GridPane.getRowIndex(node), 3, table));
              try{// then try to add/subtract
                  if(selected){// if checked add 10
                     targetTextFeild.setText(String.valueOf(
                         Integer.parseInt(targetTextFeild.getText())+10));
                  }
                  else if(!selected){ // if unchecked subtract 10
                          targetTextFeild.setText(String.valueOf(
                           Integer.parseInt(targetTextFeild.getText())-10));
                  }
               }catch(Exception e){// do nothing}
           });
        }
    }
}
```

Then add this method in the **`tabPane ChangeListener`**:

```
tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>(){
    ......
    ......
    // I think you have here anchorPane not containerB in the original code
    changeByTen((GridPane) containerB.getChildren().get(0));
}
```

---

**Test**

[image: Test]

Comment: @Junaid If you any question about the answer please tell me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Yahya  :)

Comment: You're absolutely right my friend @Yahya. And thanks for always guiding me :)

Comment: Hi @Yahya Can you please help me on this question [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574543/javafx-how-to-calulcate-average-from-the-values-of-dynimically-created-textfiel)