# JavaFX: How to add serveral series dynimically on Area Chart and delete line(series) from chart?

Tags: java, javafx, charts, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am working with Area Chart of JavaFX. I want to add series dynamically after user will enter values in text fields and press Add button. I also want to add delete and undo functionality in it. Delete functionality working would be like for instance  if there are several lines on the Area Chart each line represents series, user can delete any line he want by clicking on that line and after clicking on delete button. I also want to add undo functionality so user can undo his actions.

The interface is like this:

[image]

For example user can draw line like this by filling text fields:

[image]

[image]

Now let say the user want to delete the series which is in red color what I want is user click on it and after click delete button it'll delete the red series like this:

[image]

So far I've tried this:

```
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class SampleController {


    @FXML
    private NumberAxis xAxis;
    @FXML
    private NumberAxis yAxis;
    @FXML
    private AreaChart<Number, Number> areaChart;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtSt;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtEt;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtNb;


    public void initialize() {

            areaChart.setTitle("Chronos");
            xAxis.setLabel("Heures");
            yAxis.setLabel("Employés");

    }


        //Button add functionality
        @FXML
        private void generateGraph() {

            //double start = Double.parseDouble(txtSt.getText());
            double end = Double.parseDouble(txtEt.getText());
            int numberEmployees = Integer.parseInt(txtNb.getText());

            XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series= new XYChart.Series<>();

            for (double start = Double.parseDouble(txtSt.getText()); start<=end; start++) {
                series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(start, numberEmployees));
            }


           // Add Series to AreaChart.
           areaChart.getData().add(series);

           //Mouse click even for series
           setOnMouseEventsOnSeries(series.getNode(), 
                   areaChart, "Series is clicked");
        }


        private void setOnMouseEventsOnSeries(Node node, 
                final AreaChart chart, final String label) {

            node.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                   chart.setTitle(label);
                }
            });

        }
}
```

FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.SampleController">
   <children>
      <AreaChart fx:id="areaChart" prefHeight="799.0" prefWidth="800.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <xAxis>
            <NumberAxis autoRanging="false" minorTickCount="1" minorTickLength="1.0" side="BOTTOM" tickLabelGap="1.0" tickLength="1.0" tickUnit="1.0" upperBound="24.0" fx:id="xAxis" />
         </xAxis>
         <yAxis>
            <NumberAxis fx:id="yAxis" autoRanging="false" minorTickLength="1.0" side="LEFT" tickLabelGap="1.0" tickUnit="1.0" upperBound="10.0" />
         </yAxis>
      </AreaChart>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="193.0" prefWidth="800.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="txtSt" promptText="Start Value" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtEt" promptText="End Value" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtNb" promptText="Number of Employees" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="71.0" prefWidth="800.0">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#generateGraph" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="137.0" text="Add" />
            <Button layoutX="342.0" layoutY="12.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="137.0" text="Delete" />
            <Button layoutX="410.0" layoutY="12.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="137.0" text="Undo" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Please someone guide me how can I achieve these functionalities.

Comment: Add your FXML file.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Question is updated

Comment: Hi @Junaid Sorry I'm not active in SO these days because I started working and barely have a time.
However, it seems you got a good answer from Sedrick. :)

Comment: It's okay @Yahya. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you get started. I added an `ArrayList` to keep up with `Series` that are added to the `Chart`. Comments are in the code. You can figure out how to delete/remove items from the `ArrayList` and/or `Chart` or how to remove items from the `ArrayList` then update the `Chart`.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

//    @FXML
//    private NumberAxis xAxis;
//    @FXML
//    private NumberAxis yAxis;
    @FXML
    private AreaChart<Number, Number> areaChart;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtSt;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtEt;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtNb;


    ArrayList<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> seriesContainer = new ArrayList();//Use an ArrayList to hold new Series!


        //Button add functionality
        @FXML
        private void generateGraph() {

            Double start = Double.parseDouble(txtSt.getText());

            Double end = Double.parseDouble(txtEt.getText());
            double numberEmployees = Integer.parseInt(txtNb.getText());

            XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series= new XYChart.Series<>();

            for (int i = start.intValue(); i <= end.intValue(); i++) {
                series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, numberEmployees));
            }


           // Add Series to series container.
           seriesContainer.add(series);

           //Add only new series to AreaChart
           for(XYChart.Series<Number, Number> entry : seriesContainer)
           {
               if(!areaChart.getData().contains(entry))
               {                    
                    areaChart.getData().add(entry);
               }
           }
        }

        private void setOnMouseEventsOnSeries(Node node, 
                final AreaChart chart, final String label) {

            node.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                   chart.setTitle(label);
                }
            });

        }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        areaChart.setTitle("Chronos");
        areaChart.getXAxis().setLabel("Heures");
        areaChart.getYAxis().setLabel("Employés");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sedrick got it. Another thing can you please tell me how can I populate through each of the series and get their X coordinates (first value and last value) and Y coordinates value. I need this because I need to store each of the series values in db.

Comment: Only one question per thread. You should make a serious attempt to solve your new issue. After that, you should open a new question.

Comment: Okay I'll post new question with what I've tried so far.

Comment: Hi @Sedrick can you please help me with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900852/javafx-how-to-deserialize-dynamically-create-area-chart-series?noredirect=1#comment78761201_45900852)